# Symfony add foreign key object in database

Tags: database, symfony, object, foreign-keys, entity

I want to upload an Incidencia to the database and when I try to upload it I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: $servicioIdservicio
```

This field is a foreign key that I take from user that in turn is taking it from services is an id so it is an integer field.

Class Incidencia:

```
use App\Entity\Usuario;
use App\Entity\Servicio;

/**
 * Incidencia
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="incidencia", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="Usuario_Servicio_idServicio", columns={"Usuario_Servicio_idServicio"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_DF7F4B4C95440347", columns={"Usuario_idUsuario"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\IncidenciaRepository")
 */
class Incidencia
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idIncidencia", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idincidencia;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fInicio", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $finicio;

     /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fFin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $ffin;

     /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="observacion", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $observacion;

     /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="archivo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $archivo;

    /**
     * @var \Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Usuario_idUsuario", referencedColumnName="idUsuario")
     * })
     */
    private $usuarioIdusuario;

    /**
     * @var \Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Usuario_Servicio_idServicio", referencedColumnName="Servicio_idServicio")
     * })
     */
    private $usuarioServicioIdservicio;
}
```

I have also tried to change $userServiceServiceIdservice from Usuario to Servicio and the same error comes up

```
$inc = new Incidencia();
            $inc->setNombre($data['incidencia']);
            $inc->setFinicio($data['finicio']);
            $inc->setFfin($data['ffin']);
            $inc->setObservacion($data['observacion']);
            if($data['archivo']=!""){
                $inc->setArchivo($data['archivo']);
            }
            
            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
            $user = $entityManager->getRepository(Usuario::class)->find(5);

            $inc->setUsuarioIdusuario($user);

            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
            $serv = $entityManager->getRepository(Servicio::class)->find(2);

            $inc->setUsuarioServicioIdservicio($user);

            $doctrine->getRepository(Incidencia::class)->addIncidencia($inc);
```

Method

```
 /**
 * @throws ORMException
 * @throws OptimisticLockException
 */
public function addIncidencia(Incidencia $entity, bool $flush = true): void
{
    $this->_em->persist($entity);
    if ($flush) {
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: *$inc->setUsuarioServicioIdservicio($serv);* instead of *$inc->setUsuarioServicioIdservicio($user);* - approach seems right, but your setting the wrong object.

Comment: I had already tried it but as it expects a Usuario I can not put a Servicio object - Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Incidencia::setUsuarioServicioIdservicio() must be an instance of App\Entity\Usuario or null, instance of Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Servicio given, called in ...\Controller\IncidenciaForm.php on line 172: public function setUsuarioServicioIdservicio(?Usuario $usuarioServicioIdservicio): self
    {
        $this->usuarioServicioIdservicio = $usuarioServicioIdservicio;
        return $this;
    }